# matlab getYahooDailyData struct object to simple matrix (double)

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

From the function `getYahooDailyData` (available on:)

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43627-download-daily-data-from-google-and-yahoo--finance/content/getYahooDailyData.m

I try the following code.

```
symbols = {'000001.SZ', '000002.SZ'}
data = getYahooDailyData(symbols, '01/01/2004', '05/11/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

data is created as a `struct` object.

```
data = 

    x000001x2ESZ: [480x7 dataset]
    x000002x2ESZ: [480x7 dataset]
```

In my case my `struct` object contains 2 `dataset` (000001.SZ and 000002.SZ).

Each dataset contains 7 column : the first col is the date the last is the adjusted price.

I would like to know how to create a new matrice with 3 column:

1. Date (which is the same for 000001.sz and 000002.sz)
2. Adj price of 000001.sz
3. Adj price of 000002.sz

And of course if I add more equities in symbols I would like to get the same kind of matrix...

PS: here is the matlab environement https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqujbs9utixcfeb/dataprices.mat?dl=0

Comment: It was complaining of this - `Error using getYahooDailyData
Too many input arguments.` after trying to run the code.

Comment: I dont get this error maybe use small letters in getyahoodailydata. Otherwise I just uploaded the post with a dropbox link containing the environement.

Comment: How about this - `[data.x0003330x2ESZ.Date data.x0003330x2ESZ.AdjClose data.x0006230x2ESZ.AdjClose]`? Not sure  if it could be this easy.

Comment: @Divakar Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in YahooTest (line 6)
[data.x0003330x2ESZ.Date data.x0003330x2ESZ.AdjClose
data.x0006230x2ESZ.AdjClose]

Comment: Well I have used the `.mat` linked in the question. Could you run it on that data?